# What's the proper way to manage login state + login view (using storyboards)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

It's the first app that I'm creating that will use FB, Twtr and custom login.
I'll be using a dedicated login view/viewcontroller for this purpose.
My idea was to check the login state in the app delegate and go from there.

[image: The startup layout]

**In case app delegate determines the user is not logged in**

- Set the login view as the root view controller
- Login will display the rest of the app modally
- If you log out, the modal view of the app is dismissed and you get back at the login screen

So in this case it looks perfect for me, but I can't figure the other case out:

**In case app delegate determines the user is logged in**

- If you set the tabbar controller as the rootViewController there is no login view to dismiss to in case the user logs out..
- I don't want the user to view the login screen if he is already logged in

A solution would be to invisibly set login vc as the root vc but immediately display the tab bar controller modally without the user noticing. I guess that's not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always start with the Login screen at the root. The login views should be invisible and a UIActivityIndicator (or similar) should be shown while you determine if the user is logged in.
If the user is logged-in, simply push the next view controller and continue normally. If he isn't un-hide the login views.

Comment: So I should keep the same storyboard layout, but check the login state in the login vc instead of the appdelegate if I understand you correctly.

Comment: Exactly. That's what I do in my apps.